# When scrolling down increment from 1 to 100

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I when I start scrolling into my div, my initial value is 0. When I reach the bottom of the div, I want my value to be 100.

Here's an example :

```js
var initial = 0;
var end = 100;

$('div').scroll(function() {
  initial++;
  console.log(initial);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus exercitationem numquam assumenda alias blanditiis, neque labore eaque veritatis dignissimos, odio atque praesentium ut, itaque! Neque sed voluptas, similique ullam omnis.lorem Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta eos quas ea quia fuga aperiam maxime amet, a odit adipisci earum autem necessitatibus. Quidem obcaecati eveniet maxime ducimus provident saepe. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
  elit. Ipsum deserunt, ipsam explicabo voluptate laborum nam odio nemo neque, libero iusto officia consequuntur dolorem quis est quod eaque? Similique, porro, et!</div>
```

In this example, if you check the console, When I scroll, the last value is 5, I want it to be 100

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I don't know if this is an easy task...i think you need to write a js function which knows the height of the div and the current position and this function has to evaluate the percentage

Comment: @Pete he wants the counter to be equal to the current percentage of the height of the div

Comment: @Pete hm maybe you're right :D OP please explain us your question :D

Comment: @messerbill kind of a mixture of the two - a percentage of the scrollable height

Answer (score 4):

You can set initial to be the percentage of the scrollable height

```js
var $test = $('.test');
var scrollableHeight = $test.height() - $test[0].scrollHeight; // get amount of scroll available

$test.scroll(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
 
  var initial = $this.scrollTop() / scrollableHeight * -100;  // divide the scroll top by the amount of scrollable height to get the percentage then times by -100 to make it a positive number out of 100
  
  console.log(parseInt(initial)); // parseInt is optional - just gives you integers
});
```

```css
.test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus exercitationem numquam assumenda alias blanditiis, neque labore eaque veritatis dignissimos, odio atque praesentium ut, itaque! Neque sed voluptas, similique ullam omnis.lorem  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta eos quas ea quia fuga aperiam maxime amet, a odit adipisci earum autem necessitatibus. Quidem obcaecati eveniet maxime ducimus provident saepe. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsum deserunt, ipsam explicabo voluptate laborum nam odio nemo neque, libero iusto officia consequuntur dolorem quis est quod eaque? Similique, porro, et!</div>
```

Comment: I came up with effectively the same thing. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qQbOjP Providing as an additional option.